# Where do I put my error trapping for password here?

Tags: asp.net

So my error-trapped code for password is this

```
if (txtPassword.Text != txtConfirmPassword.Text)
    lblErrorMessage.Text = "Password do not match!";
```

I'm having a hard time where will I put it since I always get an error.

```
btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserCreateOrUpdate",sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",(hfUserID.Value==""?0:Convert.ToInt32(hfUserID.Value)));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName",txtFName.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName",txtLName.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        string userID = hfUserID.Value;
    Clear();
    if (userID == "")
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Saved Successfully";
    else
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully";
    FillGridView();
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and share what error exactly you get? Please edit the question and add this very important detail to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Attention TODO Help In Code.

```
  btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
               bool isUpdate=false;

                if (txtPassword.Text != txtConfirmPassword.Text)
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = "Password do not match!";

                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();

                if(hfUserID.Value!="")
                {             
               // TODO: Check UserId there is In Table Or not(Similar to the bottom ADO.net).
               // TODO: then If Exist then isUpdate=true else isUpdate=false
                }                  

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserCreateOrUpdate",sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",(hfUserID.Value==""?0:Convert.ToInt32(hfUserID.Value)));
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName",txtFName.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName",txtLName.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

                int a= sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlCon.Close();

                Clear();

            if (a==0)
                lblSuccessMessage.Text =isUpdate? "Not updated.":"Not Saved";
            else
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = isUpdate? "Updated." : "Saved";

            FillGridView();
        }
```